# Inno Setup Uninstalling Optional Packages

Tags: inno-setup

When uninstalling my app using Inno Setup I provide a page to allow the user to optionally uninstall some third party libraries associated with the software.

Before uninstalling my app I first call Exec() for each of those selected application's uninstall files as detailed below for PostgreSQL:

```
function UninstallPostgres() : Boolean;
var
  Value : String;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if not IsWin64 or not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PostgreSQL 8.4', 'UninstallString', Value) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKLM32, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PostgreSQL 8.4', 'UninstallString', Value);

  if (Value <> '') then
    Result := Exec(Value, '--mode unattended --unattendedmodeui none', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

It all works fine except the ewWaitUntilTerminated seems to be ignored and the program continues to execute while PostgreSQL is uninstalling. .

I'm guessing this is because the uninstall file that is executed for PostgresSQL is terminating but kicking off a further process in the background to complete the uninstallation.

Has anyone encountered this problem and if so do they have a more elegant solution than simply polling the registry key to check if PostgreSQL has indeed been removed before allowing execution to continue?

Comment: Did you try to find out what sub-process is started? Maybe you can run the sub-process directly, skipping the master one.

Comment: Unfortunately the sub-process name changes each time you run the install. I'm also at a loss of how to get the required arguments into it. I'll probably just go with polling the registry until the key no longer exists.